# Is there a Checkstyle-like tool to monitor XHTML (or XML) pages?

Tags: xhtml, sonarqube, checkstyle

I am working on a project where we have many JSF pages - using the **XHTML** format.
We monitor the quality of our code using [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) (and thus Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs...). This works great for the Java part of our application.

Now, I want to have a tool (ideally something that could then be linked to Sonar by writing my own plugin) that checks the XHTML part of my application.

So, is there a checkstyle-like tool that can check for some rules on my pages? For example, this tool will raise a warning when I encounter these kind of code:

```
<h:inputText ...></h:inputText> (instead of <h:inputText .../>)
```

or :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
     ...
</h:panelGrid> (a <h:panelGroup> is better here)
```

I'm aware that Checkstyle offers a rule that is based on a regular expression, but I fear that solution is too complex for some rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently found the [Sonar Web plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Plugin) that provides static code analysis of JSP and JSF files. The main features of this plugin are:

- sizing (files, lines of code)
- rules compliancy
- complexity
- duplication
- comments

I will try it soon (I need to install the latest Sonar 2.2 version) and give feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the venerable "[HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)".  Or you could consider [extending checkstyle](http://checkstyle.2069334.n4.nabble.com/checkstyle-for-javascript-tc2070973.html) itself.

You might want to focus attention here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-130